# How can I automatically reset the selected value of a h:selectOneMenu if it becomes invalid?

Tags: ajax, jsf, selectonemenu

- Select value "A" from pulldown1, pulldown2 gets populated with items "A1", "A2", "A3", etc.
- Select value "A1" from pulldown2
- Select value "B" from pulldown1, pulldown2 gets populated with items "B1", "B2", "B3", etc.  (Although it doesn't look like anything is selected, 'A1' is actually still there because when I...)
- Select value "A" from pulldown1 again, pulldown2 is re-populated with "A1" !

Is there a way to automatically set the value of the selectOneMenu to null if its current selection is invalid?

```
<h:panelGroup id="locationInformationPanel">

<h:selectOneMenu id="pulldown1">
    <f:ajax listener="#{LocationSelector.siteNameChangeListener}"
            render="locationInformationPanel" execute="@this"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems  value="#{LocationSelector.siteNames}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneMenu id="pulldown2">
    <f:ajax listener="#{LocationSelector.buildingChangeListener}"
            render="locationInformationPanel" execute="@this"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems  value="#{LocationSelector.buildings}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

</h:panelGroup>
```

```
public void siteNameChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
   String selectedSiteName = getSelectionsFromEvent(e);
    updateBuildings(selectedSiteName);
}
```

NOTE: These menu's don't have any "value" fields bound to them but, even when I bind them, it still happens.  The bound fields end up holding the first, invalid, value

Comment: When exactly is that `<h:selectOneMenu>`'s *current selection* is considered invalid - upon conversion/validation errors?

Comment: I'm using the term "invalid" to describe anything that isn't currently in the select item list.  I'm not talking about any phase in particular...I just want a pulldown to automatically unset the selected value if the backend select items change and the value isn't there anymore.  I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: @Tiny As I mentioned below, I'm trying not to manage this with binding a value to the menu and then manipulating that value in the backend.  I want to save that value binding for another object that will ultimately use the value.  If I don't do that, then I have to bind that value to something in the LocationSelector, then copy that value to the other object when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the "right" way, but I added 'pulldown2' to the execute attribute of the ajax tag in pulldown1 and it worked:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="pulldown1">
    <f:ajax listener="#{LocationSelector.siteNameChangeListener}"
            render="locationInformationPanel" execute="@this pulldown2"/>
```

Any feedback on this approach?

Comment: Do you understand what happens when you apply this approach?

Comment: I'm guessing, when pulldown2 "executes" it somehow sees that the selected option is no longer an actual option and sets it to "null" or something.  Although I'm starting to wonder whether this is a good solution because, honestly, it seems like managing the value with this default unknown behavior is very risk-prone.

Comment: @kolossus My goal is to have the select items be managed with one object and the values be managed by another, unrelated object.  That way I can just plug in any value-managing object I want and still use the same select item management backend.  I don't know if this is possible, though, because it seems that I'm too reliant on the AjaxBehaviorEvent to carry over the value data to the select item management object.  In fact, I actually cache this value in the object for further use.